# Set different css stylesheet for specific pages

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

Is it possible to assign a css stylesheet to specific pages only?

If so how?

Can I use something like this? Not sure how to specify the pages though?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_css' );

function enqueue_theme_css()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'default',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/default.css'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to check whether you are on a specific page or not. For example, this will enqueue your scripts only for the page that has the `contact-us` slug:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_css' );

function enqueue_theme_css()
{
    if( is_page( 'contact-us' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'default',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/default.css'
        );
    }
}
```

You can take a look into the [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function for more informations.